# MSSQL - User Defined Function or Aggregate

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm working on move a project over to a new database design. In doing so I am going to need to update existing stored procedures to work with new the new tables.

In the stored procedure I am working, I have the following:

[image]

When I hover over the String.Trim , it tells me that it is unable to find a column string or a user defined function or aggregate string.

After encountering this error, I went back to the stored procedure on the old database, and found that 'String'  is was a schema.

So I have gone back to my new database and have created the schema String as follows:

```
USE [databarn]
GO

/****** Object:  Schema [String]    Script Date: 2/3/2015 9:27:54 AM ******/
CREATE SCHEMA [String]
GO
```

This was created successfully and is now located in the Security>Schemas.

However going back to my stored procedure, the String reference is still underlined in red with the original message.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Does the function belong to the String schema? Also, sometimes Intellisense takes a while to refresh and will give false indication of missing objects - try refreshing the local Intellisense cache using `Ctrl+Shift+R`

Comment: did you create the function TRIM? because SQL does not have TRIM. It does have RTRIM and LTRIM

Comment: That was the issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is c# type of coding. In sqlserver it is differ, it have inbuilt function.

`Trim` function in `c#`, to achieve in same in `sqlserver` you need to use `RTRIM` and `LTRIM` like

```
select rtrim(ltrim(' a b c d '))
```

First of all you need to know the basic functions in sqlserver.

[String related function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx).

[Built in function in sqlserver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174318.aspx)